# Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP causes activity to pop-up even when application is on background?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I'm using Android 2.2. I have an application which logouts (causing the application to return to the login page) after a certain period of inactivity. I am using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` for my `Intent`. However, I notice that when my application is on background and is inactive for a certain period of time, the login page suddenly pops-up and my application goes to foreground. I am expecting that the login page will remain to background. This does not happen when I am not using any flag for my intent. If I'm not using any flag for my Intent, the login page is quietly started on the background. But without using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, I won't be able to clear my history stack.

Why is this happening? How can I launch an activity on background quietly?

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
@Override //Inside a class extending AsyncTask
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    ((GlobalApplication)getApplicationContext()).setIsLogin(false); //user is not logged in anymore
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Below is a snippet the code I made from Lars' suggestion:

```
@Override //Inside a class extending AsyncTask
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    ((GlobalApplication)getApplicationContext()).setIsLogin(false); //user is not logged in anymore
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    if(((GlobalApplication)getApplicationContext()).isOnBackground())
        ((GlobalApplication)getApplicationContext()).setPendingIntent(intent);
    else
        startActivity(intent);
}

@Override //overrides android.app.Activity. inside the current Activity
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Intent pendingIntent = ((GlobalApplication)getApplicationContext()).getPendingIntent();
    if(pendingIntent != null)
        startActivity(pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: This looks like normal behavior for this Intent, could you give us the snippet of code where you use this Intent ?

Comment: @Sephy: Thanks for commenting! What did you mean by it's the normal behavior? Did you mean that I should expect the activity to pop up when I am launching an intent using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP even the application is on background? As requested, I've added a snippet of my code.

Comment: Is your log screen thrown on the pile when the AsyncTask finishes? Because your call is in the onPostExecute so it will be executed when the stuff in the task is finished...

Comment: Well, the documentation states this : "If set, and **the activity being launched is already running** in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent." So yes, it looks to me like normal behavior, especially if this is thrown when your AsyncTask finishes !

Comment: This is entirely expected. You *are* starting an activity after all, how do you expect it to.. you know, not start? 
The way to implement this would be to set a flag from your postExecute and check that flag in every Activity's onResume. BroadcastReceivers from the manifest would need some fiddling too.

Comment: @Sephy: Yes, I am launching the login activity inside the onPostExecute method because I am connecting to a web service inside the doInBackground method. It's okay for me if it will be using my old login activity. However, if my AsyncTask finishes when my application is on background. It causes my application to launch the login activity (which is normal) and return to foreground (which I don't know why it's happening). I am expecting that the login activity will be launched quietly in the background.

Comment: @Delyan: Can't I start an activity on the background quietly? In a way that I will only see the login activity when I open my application again. I tried launching the login activity without the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and the login activity does not pop up even my application is on background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried checking if you are still logged in in the onResume part of your activities instead of calling your LoginActivity when a timer goes off (which is what I'm assuming you are doing)?

Edit: For clarification, you are logging the user out after a predefined period of time (or when an event occurs). At this point you start an AsyncTask which creates an intent for your loginActivity, adds a flag to it and starts it. And your problem is that you don't want the loginActivity to come to the foreground unless the user has the application open. Is that accurate?

Because if so I would recommend using the onResume methods like I mentioned above. These are called whenever an activity comes (back) to the foreground. For showing the login screen even when the user doesn't change activities you could try sending a broadcast and listening for it in your activities.

EDIT: Code snippet from my comment (Now correctly formatted):

```
@Override    
     protected void onResume() {   
         super.onResume();   
         if (!getLoggedIn())   
         {  
              startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));   
              finish();   
         }   
     }
```

Comment: Yes, I'm calling the login activity when the timer goes off. But I'm also resetting the login indicator before calling the login activity. So the if I checked my login indicator on the onResume part, I'm not logged in anymore.

Comment: You can still set the login indicator in your asynctask, but instead of calling the loginActivity when the timer finishes, you might want to try calling it from your onResume method after checking your login indicator. This should only launch the loginActivity when your application comes back to the foreground or switches activities, and not when it is in the background and the timer fires.

It would look something like this:
`@Override

 protected void onResume()
 {
  super.onResume();

  if (!getLoggedIn())
  {
   startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
   finish();
  }
 }`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the stackoverflow markup... apologies for the lack of formatting in the code

Comment: Thanks, Lars! I will try your suggestion. I'm coding it now.

Comment: @Lars if you give snippet of code in the comments of your answer, I would suggest to edit your own post and add the formatted code there because comments are not really good at rendering this.

Comment: @Sephy I tried, but I guess I just really suck at formatting. Tried indenting the code with 4 spaces, but that just doesn't do anything.
I just hope Arci can read it so he can solve his problem

Comment: @Lars: It worked! But I modified your code. I will edit my post above to include my code. Please tell me if I made it wrong. I already tested it and it's working but I could miss something. Also, does finish destroys the current activity? I thought anything under startActivity won't be executed anymore since I already left my current activity making finish unreachable?

Comment: I believe than when you call finish() it will always destroy the current activity (since you are calling it from a running activity, else you couldn't call it).

Comment: Since I can't comment on your post for some reason, I'll post it here.
Is the onResume function in the AsyncTask or in your other activities?

It looks good, clever of you to use a pendingIntent, I might actually update my current project to use that solution as well.

Comment: @Lars: The onResume function is inside my Activity. It overrides the onResume function of android.app.Activity. I can't comment also on other people's post except if I started the thread. I think It's because we don't have the required reputation to comment yet.

Comment: @Arci: Looks good then, remember you will need to override the onResume function in all activities where you want to be able to jump out of to go to the LoginActivity and you should be good to go then.
As for the commenting, I guess you're right, but this works fine as well for now :)

Comment: @Lars: Thanks again! Yes, I need to override it in all my activities. Good thing, I made a base class so I only need to override it once.